# NSMutableArray to table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i am new to the iPhone development.
i need to display the NSMutableArray contents into UITableViewCell.. 
it is quite simple.. but, i want to know, how to add the NSMutableArray contents into table view at runtime?
please anyone help me.. 
                 thank you very much..!

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)?

In particular the section that talks about [Creating and Configuring a Table View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10).

The little code snippets on those guides provide examples that deal with the simplest case, which is an array.

In short, you provide a "data source", which the table view asks for each row from.  That data source is usually (but doesn't have to be) the ViewController that uses the table.

Make sure to check out the example applications linked to there if you need to see some working examples in Xcode itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add total array to single cell or a tableView. If the answer is tableView, then you can directly give the values in the following method like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [array count];
}
```

you can use like that.